# finding out different ways of telling a number having some repeating continuous digits

Tags: algorithm, math

if there is an integer say 111 then there are 4 ways in which it can be said: 
1. one one one
2. double two one
3. one double two
4. triple one

so how can one generate all possible ways for any integer eg. 33356777 etc. 
I think this can be done by automata but can't figure out how programatically
Thanks.

Comment: the number of possibilities to descrine d^n [n times digit d] as explained in the question is exponential. Are you looking for the number of options or the actual ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways to "say" `d^n` where `d` is the digit and `n` is the number of repeats is simply `2^(n-1)`.

Why? For each place between the repeating digit at place i and place (i+1): You can either "stop there" and tell the generated number so far, and advance to the next - or you can keep counting the d's and go on. You repeat it for each i.

To sum it all up, you go through your number, and multiply all of these: for exampe `33356777` will be `2^2 * 2^0 * 2^0 * 2^2 = 16`